# Rearranging $\left| \sqrt{x} -\sqrt{y} \right| $

Tags: real-analysis

I'm just going through an example of a Holder function ($f(x) = \sqrt{x}$), and a step in the example goes as follows,

$$\left| \sqrt{x} -\sqrt{y} \right| = \frac{\left|x-y\right|}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}$$

I've been fiddling around with this for half an hour and cannot see how to get the RHS from the left.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

$(\sqrt x-\sqrt y)(\sqrt x+\sqrt y) = (\sqrt x)^2 - (\sqrt y)^2 = x - y$

Comment: Okay I can see how you get the rearrangement, but why wouldn't there be an absolute value on the denominator?

Comment: $\sqrt x + \sqrt y$ is always positive.